# Is "sustain" = "not set aside"

Tags: florida, court-order

Nonbinding Arbitration: An `order of default` is entered.   Defense files to set aside the default.

In order to request that the the order of default `not be set aside`, is it proper (commonplace in the craft) to request that the order be `sustained`?  Or is there a better (concise) word?

Title of document:

```
1) PETITIONER’S MOTION TO SUSTAIN ORDER OF DEFAULT
2) PETITIONER’S MOTION TO AFFIRM ORDER OF DEFAULT
3) PETITIONER’S MOTION TO CONFIRM ORDER OF DEFAULT
```

Comment: Please don't use codeblocks for text that is not actual code.

Comment: @Nij  Sure.  Can I ask why?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301372/341260

Answer (score 2):

It would be more common to ask that the request to set aside be **denied** or that the order of default be **affirmed** or **confirmed**. It probably isn't wrong to say **sustained**, but that word isn't commonly used outside of evidence objections, and it isn't totally clear if you are talking about sustaining the order of default, or sustaining the objection to the order of default.

Comment: Always good to hear from you.  Please consider commenting as to which word you would use and why?  Thank you

Comment: I would ask that their request be denied.